# MySQL Advanced multidimensional query with CONCAT, JSON and IF statement

Tags: php, mysql, json

I working on one complex listing from database and decide to do all possible requests via one query.

Here is working example:

```
"SELECT
    `c`.`categories_id`,
    `c`.`categories_status`,
    IF(`c`.`categories_status` = 1, 'Active', 'Not Active') AS `categories_status_name`,
    TRIM(`cd`.`categories_name`) AS `categories_name`,
    TRIM(`cd`.`concert_date`) AS `concert_date`,
    TRIM(`cd`.`concert_time`) AS `concert_time`,
    TRIM((
        SELECT
            CONCAT(
                '{\"total_quantity\":',
                    SUM(CASE WHEN `p`.`products_quantity` > 0 THEN `p`.`products_quantity` ELSE 0 END),
                ',\"total_price\":\"',
                    SUM(`p`.`products_price`),
                '\"}'
            )
        FROM
            `products_to_categories` `ptc`,
            `products` `p`
        WHERE
            `ptc`.`section_id` = `cd`.`section_id`
        AND
            `p`.`products_id` = `ptc`.`products_id`
    )) AS `products_available`,
    TRIM((
        SELECT
            CONCAT(
                '{\"total_quantity\":',
                    SUM(CASE WHEN `op`.`products_quantity` > 0 THEN `op`.`products_quantity` ELSE 0 END),
                ',\"total_price\":\"',
                    SUM(`op`.`final_price`),
                '\"}'
            )
        FROM
            `products_to_categories` `ptc`,
            `orders_products` `op`
        WHERE
            `ptc`.`section_id` = `cd`.`section_id`
        AND
            `op`.`products_id` = `ptc`.`products_id`
        AND
            `op`.`orders_products_status` != 1
    )) AS `products_sold`,
    TRIM((
        SELECT
            CONCAT(
                '{\"total_quantity\":',
                    SUM(CASE WHEN `op`.`products_quantity` > 0 THEN `op`.`products_quantity` ELSE 0 END),
                ',\"total_price\":\"',
                    SUM(`op`.`final_price`),
                '\"}'
            )
        FROM
            `products_to_categories` `ptc`,
            `orders_products` `op`
        WHERE
            `ptc`.`section_id` = `cd`.`section_id`
        AND
            `op`.`products_id` = `ptc`.`products_id`
        AND
            `op`.`orders_products_status` = 1
    )) AS `products_pending`
FROM
    `categories` `c`,
    `categories_description` `cd`
WHERE
    `c`.`categories_id`  = `c`.`section_id`
AND
    `cd`.`categories_id`  = `c`.`categories_id`
GROUP BY `c`.`categories_id`
ORDER BY `c`.`categories_status` DESC;"
```

This work great but my main problem is how to do check IF/ELSE or CASE WHEN for custom defined new fields: `products_available`, `products_sold` and `products_pending`?

Problem is that if products not exists inside table `orders_products` I not get my generated JSON and that's made a small conflict inside PHP.

I can do check in PHP but want to avoid that part and just print JSON like:

```
{"total_quantity":0,"total_price":"0.0000"}
```

Comment: Would you please tell one sample condition that you want to test for custom fields, say for- products_available?

Comment: Problem is that if products not exists inside table `orders_products` I not get generated JSON from `products_available`. I get only empty field. I need to have instand empty field JSON like `{"total_quantity":0,"total_price":"0.0000"}`. That's only reason.

Answer (score -1):

```
FROM
    `products_to_categories` `ptc`,
    `orders_products` `op`
    *

WHERE `products_id` = 
(SELECT COALESCE(`products_id`,0))

*
AND
    `ptc`.`section_id` = `cd`.`section_id`
```

Comment: Please include explanations to your answer. The goal of StackOverflow is not only to provide solutions but explanations too.

Comment: The COALESCE takes two arguments and returns first argument that is not null.